# Getting Artihmetic Exception Error

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions

I wrote this program. But I am getting Arithmetic Exception Error.
Program:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int fact(int n)
{
    int facte = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        facte *= i;
    return facte;
}
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int res = 0;
    int temp = k;
    int term1, term2, term3;
    while ((n - temp) > 1)
    {
        term1 = fact(n);
        term2 = fact(n - temp);
        term3 = fact(temp);
        res = int((term1 / (term2 * term3)));
        sum1 += res;
        temp--;
    }

    cout << sum1 * fact(n - k - 1) + 1;
}
```

Input:

```
n=4 and k=2
```

Error:

```
 GDB trace:
    Reading symbols from solution...done.
    [New LWP 18123]
    Core was generated by `solution'.
    Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
    #0  main () at solution.cc:29
    29        res=int((term1/(term2*term3)));
    #0  main () at solution.cc:29
```

Comment: `term2` or `term3` must be zero.

Comment: do `p term2` and `p term3` to see what values they have

Comment: I think it should be `sum1 += res;` in place of `sum += res;`

Comment: try this  res=int((term1/term2)/term3);

Comment: @Victor Why is your suggestion different from what OP is doing?

Comment: Unrelated: Use the combination of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` with caution. Neither are recommended practice and together they can result in hard-to-comprehend bugs and errors.

Comment: term1,term2,term3 cannot be zero as fact function will return value>=1

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius who is op? and what is he doing?

Comment: @Victor OP = Original Poster.

Comment: aha - the old. 'it cant be zero cos my analysis is that that cant happen' rather than actually looking with a debugger

Comment: @Ron No, I did write the code.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius there are factotial calculations, I suspect int varialbles overflow. Thus suggesting not multiply two large numbers.

Comment: @Adil, try what I said before

Comment: Please edit your question and add the inputs which are being used to expose the error.

Comment: @victor right the obvious thing here is overflow. factorials get very big very fast

Comment: @Victor Fair enough, but I still feel that it's delaying the problem one step further - there's nothing stopping the factorial calculation in `fact` to overflow (we don't even know if it doesn't in the current case, since we don't know the inputs OP is using). I would, personally, in addition to this, suggest to use `unsigned` integer type, so that, at the very least, the overflow wouldn't be undefined behavior.

Comment: Wait a sec. `while ((n - temp) > 1)` and `temp--;` When does this loop ever exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying two factorial number can overflow int.

Replace

```
 res = int((term1 / (term2 * term3)));
```

with

```
  res = (term1 / term2) / term3;
```

// added parenthesis just to be sure
also change

```
 temp--;
```

to

```
temp++;
```

Comment: And that's assuming the factorials themselves did not overflow.

Comment: Right. But if they did that would have raised exception earlier. In such case use long int or other suitable type.

Comment: I am just giving n=4 and k=2, not large values

Comment: Not necessarily. `fact`  could be rolling around in undefined behaviour land for quite some time undetected.

Comment: @AdilMahmood Edit your question and add those inputs to it.

Comment: ALso you sure there should be temp-- not temp++? It looks like an endless cycle

Comment: it was actuallu temp++.

Comment: got the answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adil, you should also be careful with multiplying, can easily give you problem on larger input numbers.

Comment: i was using temp-- mistakenly. corrected to temp++ and got the answer

Comment: @AdilMahmood you would have found that bug a lot sooner if you'd single-stepped the debugger  and kept an eye on the value of temp..